# how to reverse-proxy a client/user from one server to another using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, node-http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

i was looking a for a way to reverse-proxy my application which is running on localhost:7200 to another server running on 10.0.0.1:3000 by using a POST request

```
apiRoutes.post('/route', function(req, res) {
res.json({ message: 'Done' });
  var tunroute=req.body.address;
  console.log(tunroute);

   //{tunroute contains the address i.e 10.0.0.1:300}

   //{ here is where i want to proxy to server at 10.0.0.1:300 }
```

});

please help!!

Comment: well your comment is out of the scope of my question.

Comment: Flagging my comment as 'obsolete/not constructive' isn't helpful, especially as your question is a simple 'plz code this for me' request which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: its not just simply a 'plz code this for me' , its more like 'i am open to suggestions ' , no hard feelings bro, i flagged it cos that comment was not appropriate to what i asked for !

Comment: Comments are not for answers, what have you tried? You need to provide an [mcve]- providing a template isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the answer, 
      i used

> http-proxy-middleware

for reverse proxying client from one server to another

here is the code for the same.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var target = ['http://www.facebook.com',
              'http://10.0.0.1:3000',
              'http://127.0.0.1']

  app.use(methodOverride());

  app.get('/change',function(req,res){

    options = {
            target: target[2],      // target host
            changeOrigin: false,    // needed for virtual hosted sites
            ws: true,               // proxy websockets
        };
    var = exampleProxy = proxy(options);

    app.use('/', exampleProxy);

    return res.redirect("./");
  });

  app.listen(3000);
```